# How to list and estimate all possible pairwise comparisons in R

Tags: r, combinations, pairwise

I need to estimate all possible pairwise combinations of a data list.

This is an example of my data
[image: This is an example of my data]
For example, for A (Column1), I need to estimate z-x, z-y and x-y differences and their reverse cases. I mean, I should get back: -10, -20, -30, and 10, 20 and 30 for reverse cases. And then I need to estimate all possible pairwise combinations for B and C following the explanation for A. I need to create a list of all pairwise combinations for 4000 data.
Also, I share a link with an Excel file with my example.
Example in Excel
[Example in Excel](http://www.filedropper.com/example_1)
I thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: See `?combn` function

Comment: Please share your data in a form we can copy and paste easily. Besides, you might read about the `?combn` function and its `FUN` argument.

Comment: Thanks Sonny and @markus. I share a link with my data in Excel.

Comment: @Calfiao it should be copy&paste-able. most people won't risk to follow the link you provide. see for an easy way https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/datapasta-reprex.html#scenario-1-from-spreadsheet-to-reprex-with-tribble_paste

Comment: You are looking for permutations since you also need the reverse.

Comment: You can still get by combn for your situation, but I’m just letting you know as the number of permutations can grow quickly. Trying to bend combn to work in those situations can be quite cumbersome and inefficient. Good luck